# How to know steps is recorded by sensors or input by user from google fit programmatically

Tags: android, google-fit

I get steps for google fit from this Code

```
PendingResult<DataReadResult> pendingResult = Fitness.HistoryApi
            .readData(
                    fitnessClient,
                    new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA,
                                    DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime,
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build());
    int steps = 0;
    DataReadResult dataReadResult = pendingResult.await();
    if (dataReadResult.getBuckets().size() > 0) {
        //Log.e("TAG", "Number of returned buckets of DataSets is: "
                //+ dataReadResult.getBuckets().size());
        for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets()) {
            List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
            for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                    for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                        steps += dp.getValue(field).asInt();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (dataReadResult.getDataSets().size() > 0) {
        for (DataSet dataSet : dataReadResult.getDataSets()) {
            for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                    steps += dp.getValue(field).asInt();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return steps;
```

Now I have a setting option in my app by that user can turn off the steps sensing by the health kit. How to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the **getOriginalDatasource** of each **DataPoint** and then you can query **Datasource** to get stream identifier. If you get **soft_step_counter** then it means its logged by user manually.

Comment: Can you please explain more @Krishna